# Exporting an access table to a text file using vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a table in MS-Access. It has only two columns: `ID` and `Name`.

I want to export only `Name` to a text file. A dialogue box should be opened, the user write the name of the text file and then the names should be saved in this text file. In the text file, each name must be on a separate row like this:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
```

how can I do this job in vba?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found it, but the problem is now, that I cant Filter and a run time error is occured

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim f As Object
Dim strFile_Path As String

Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).Show
strFile_Path = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).SelectedItems.Item(1)


MsgBox strFile_Path

Open strFile_Path For Output As #1
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Name FROM tb_lable_Daten", dbOpenSnapshot)
Do While Not rst.EOF
    Print #1, rst!name
    rst.MoveNext
Loop
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Close #1
```